# Why am I missing $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR and $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS after logging in via SSH and trying to set up user scope service

Tags: ssh, systemd, environment-variables

I'm trying to set up a user scope service after logging in via SSH, but when I try setting anything up like..

```
systemctl --user enable wallpaper.timer
```

I get these errors, even though I'm logged in via SSH as the user in question..

```
Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=<user>@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)
```

`env` confirms those particular environment variables are not set. But the following works for some reason.

```
sudo systemctl --machine=<user>@.host --user enable wallpaper.timer
```

which is annoying and seems roundabout.  I have to sudo to get access to my own user environment variables.  Right now, I don't see the point in setting up services this way over just using root services and setting `User=<username>`.

How can I log into SSH user account and have $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR and $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS set?  I've tried `ssh` and `ssh -t` with same results.

Answer (score 1):

$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR and $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS were not being set when logging in via SSH because I had turned off PAM system in the host's SSH server configuration.

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd.config
```

and setting

```
UsePAM yes
```

fixed it.

Apparently, it is the PAM system that controls these variables.